# header attribute in div

Tags: html, angularjs

```js
<body ng-controller="MainController as mainCtrl" ng-app="MyApp">
    <div header page="'Test'" ></div>
    <div id="main" class="app-body" ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
        <my-grid-list></my-grid-list>
    </div>
</body>
```

I am trying to figure out how the header is constructed. I expect it to be something like 
`<header-bar></header-bar>`. However, it gives `header`. Is it an attribute or some dialect of AngularJS syntax? This is AngularJS.

Comment: The `header` attribute is not a core directive in AngularJS. It could be a custom directive. Check the code for the app to see if it is defined there.

Comment: I found this.`MyApp.directive('header', function () {....})`

Comment: It's clear.header is a directive which return '<header-bar>' .

Answer (score 1):

The `header` attribute is not a core directive in AngularJS. It could be a custom directive. Check the code for the app to see if it is defined there.

> I found this.
>
> ```
> MyApp.directive('header', function () {.
>     // ...
> })
> ```

That is indeed a custom directive.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)